USB with only 2 green and 2 white cables
I found an old USB cord and cut the bad ends off to extend a shorter cord in a pinch. There are only 2 green and 2 white wires inside. No black,white or red. What is this and how do I connect it?

never connect wires solely by color ... wire colors are not standardized ... use an ohmmeter

You have 1 cable with 2 green and 2 white wires, not multiple cables.

@jsotola in theory, for USB 1 and 2, they are standardised - but a few manufacturers don't follow the standard and aren't really allow to put a "USB" label on their products.  This one doesn't even look like twisted pair.

I'd suggest to use a multimeter and ring every wire individually versus the contacts at the connector. This way you will know with confidence to where it's connected and what's the intended function.
